# Fractal shell in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fractals

I've been trying to draw a fractal shell in Python, where I have to input the size and the amount of levels. An error keeps showing up every time I try to implement the code. I've tried researching how to draw a shell in Python, to see what I can fix, but I can't seem to find anything useful. Any help on this would be great.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
  import math
  import turtle
  from turtle import* 

  turtle = turtle.Turtle()
  t= turtle
  t.speed(1000)
  print("MENU")
  def main():
      print ("1. Polygon Fractal")
      print("2. Fractal Shell")
      print("3. Snowflake")
      print("4. Fractal Tree")
      print("5. Exit")
      x=input("Please select a number")

      if x=="1":
          z=input("Please input the number of sides")
          a=input("Please input length")
          polygon(int(z),int(a))

      if x=="2":
          f=input("Please input a size")
          j=input("Please input a level")
          fractalshell(int(f),int(j))

      if x=="3":
          b=input("Please input a length")
          snowflake(int(b))

      if x=="4":
          fractaltree()

      if x=="5":
          t.hideturtle()
          done()

  def polygon(n,l):
      f = (n - 2) * 180/n
      for i in range(n):
          t.forward(l)
          t.right(180 - f)


  def fractalshell(size, level):
      def curve(size):
          t.right(45)
          for curve in range(0.1 *(size)):
              t.forward(0.1*(size))
              t.right(15)
          t.right(170)
          for curve in range(0.12*(size)):
              t.forward(0.1*(size))
              t.left(15)
      if (level > 0):        
          t.forward(size)
          curve(size)
          t.right(45)
          fractalshell = (0.93 * (size), level - 1)'
```

Here is the error that keeps appearing:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/isabelavaldes/Dropbox/Recursion.py", line 113, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/isabelavaldes/Dropbox/Recursion.py", line 27, in main
      fractalshell(int(f),int(j))
    File "/Users/isabelavaldes/Dropbox/Recursion.py", line 59, in 
  fractalshell
      curve(size)
    File "/Users/isabelavaldes/Dropbox/Recursion.py", line 50, in curve
      for curve in range(0.1 *(size)):
  TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: The error message is quite understandable: `0.1*size` is a float (of course), and `range` doesn't like floats. Check what `size` is - `if 0.1*size` can be made an integer, then do so; otherwise you have to decide what you want to happen with a non-integer value.

Comment: The "shell" tag is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You problem seems to be more related to Python syntax than Fractal Shells.  For example, it's not clear how you expected this to work:

```
fractalshell = (0.93 * (size), level - 1)'
```

where `fractalshell` is the name of the function we're in and this seems to want to be a recursive call to it, but isn't.  I reworked your code to the point that it's runnable (and more of a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def fractalshell(size, level):

    def curve(size):
        turtle.right(45)

        for step in range(int(10 * size)):
            turtle.forward(0.1 * step)
            turtle.right(15)

        turtle.right(170)

        for step in range(int(12 * size)):
            turtle.forward(0.8333 * step)
            turtle.left(15)

    if level > 0:
        turtle.forward(size)
        curve(size)
        turtle.right(45)
        fractalshell(0.93 * size, level - 1)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

f = input("Please input a size: ")
j = input("Please input a level: ")

fractalshell(int(f), int(j))

turtle.hideturtle()

screen.mainloop()
```

It currently produces interesting shapes but I'm not they're what you wanted:

[image]

**INPUT**

```
Please input a size: 5
Please input a level: 3
```